# What is Rama Rajya?

Tags: ramayana, rama

From childhood till now we all hear about **Rama Rajya.** But what exactly is Rama Rajya? What is its description? I have asked so many times to *sants* but they are also not giving me a satisfied answer. If any one who knows it better please tell me.

Comment: You can accept the best answer you like by selecting the check mark under the answer.

Answer (score 20):

Rama Rajya is described in **Yuddha Kanda** of **Valmiki Ramayana** after Rajya-Abhishekam of Lord Rama. Here is how Rama Rajya is described:

> न पर्यदेवन्विधवा न च व्यालकृतं भयम् | 
>   न व्याधिजं भयन् वापि रामे राज्यं प्रशासति || ६-१२८-९९ 
>  
>   **While Rama was ruling** the kingdom, there were **no widows to lament, nor there was no danger from wild animals, nor any fear born of diseases.**
>
> निर्दस्युरभवल्लोको नानर्थः कन् चिदस्पृशत् | 
>   न च स्म वृद्धा बालानां प्रेतकार्याणि कुर्वते || ६-१२८-१०० 
>  
>   The world was **bereft of thieves and robberies.** No one felt worthless nor did old people perform obsequies concerning youngsters.
>
> सर्वं मुदितमेवासीत्सर्वो धर्मपरोअभवत् | 
>   राममेवानुपश्यन्तो नाभ्यहिन्सन्परस्परम् || ६-१२८-१०१ 
>  
>   **Every creature felt pleased. Every one was intent on virtue. Turning their eyes towards Rama alone, creatures did not kill one another.**
>
> आसन्वर्षसहस्राणि तथा पुत्रसहस्रिणः | 
>   निरामया विशोकाश्च रामे राज्यं प्रशासति || ६-१२८-१०२ 
>  
>   **While Rama was ruling the kingdom, people survived for thousands of years, with thousands of their progeny, all free of illness and grief.**
>
> रामो रामो राम इति प्रजानामभवन् कथाः | 
>   रामभूतं जगाभूद्रामे राज्यं प्रशासति || ६-१२८-१०३ 
>  
>   While Rama ruled the kingdom, the talks of the people centered round Rama, Rama and Rama. **The world became Rama's world.**
>
> नित्यपुष्पा नित्यफलास्तरवः स्कन्धविस्तृताः | 
>   कालवर्षी च पर्जन्यः सुखस्पर्शश्च मारुतः || ६-१२८-१०४ 
>  
>   **The trees there were bearing flowers and fruits regularly, without any injury by pests and insects. The clouds were raining in time and the wind was delightful to the touch.**
>
> ब्राह्मणाः क्षत्रिया वैश्याः शूद्रा लोभविवर्जिताः | 
>   स्वकर्मसु प्रवर्तन्ते तुष्ठाः स्वैरेव कर्मभिः || ६-१२८-१०५ 
>   आसन् प्रजा धर्मपरा रामे शासति नानृताः | 
>  
>   Brahmins (the priest-class), Kshatriyas (the warrior-class), Vaishyas (the class of merchants and agriculturists), Shudras (the servant-class) were performing their own duties, satisfied with their own work and bereft of any greed. While Rama was ruling, **the people were intent on virtue and lived without telling lies.**
>
> सर्वे लक्षणसम्पन्नाः सर्वे धर्मपरायणाः || ६-१२८-१०६ 
>   दशवर्षसहस्राणि रामो राज्यमकारयत् | 
>  
>   **All the people were endowed with excellent characteristics. All were engaged in virtue.** Rama was engaged in the kingship thus for ten thousand years.

Comment: In  a nutshell, all were in their order in Rama's rule and people lived happily. There is a saying when people engaged in bad activities like muder, theft etc it will affect the king also. In Rama's rule nothing of that sorts and he was not affected. That is called Rama Rajya.

Comment: It should be 10 thousands years in last verse. What do you think?

Comment: I think this whole part is an interpolation, there are always diseases, thieves, robbery. Creatures will kill each other for their survival. Moreover, Sita herself says in Valmiki Ramayan that life span is 100 years and then it says people survived for 1000 years. I think Rama Rajya was very good but it is extremely exaggerated to the point that it no longer looks real.

Comment: @Triyugi http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga128/yuddha_128_frame.htm uses **Rajyam Varsha Sahasraani...** " in that verse.. so makes it thousand years... I don't know whether actual verse is "Rajyam Varsha Sahasraani" or "Dasha Varsha Sahasraani"...

Comment: @Chinmay Sarupriya as Divinity of Rama was revealed after Ravana Vadh... so it's possible that Rama Rajya was miraculous...

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria It could not  be interpolation. Rama Rajya is very famous as ideal kingdom. I think it was exactly as mentioned and Rama was God Himself.

Answer (score 15):

Apart from Valmiki Ramayana, Ram Rajya is described in [Ramcharitmanas, Uttar Kand](https://www.ramcharitmanas.iitk.ac.in/ramcharitmanas?tid=7&tid_1=11&tid_2=8). Very long description has been given from Doha number 20.

> राम राज बैंठें त्रेलोका। हरषित भए गए सब सोका।। 
>   बयरु न कर काहू सन कोई। राम प्रताप बिषमता खोई।।
>
> Sri Råma's installation to the throne brought joy to all the three spheres and ended all their sorrows. No one bore enmity to another; Sri Råma's glory had obliterated all disharmony.
>
> बरनाश्रम निज निज धरम बनिरत बेद पथ लोग। 
>   चलहिं सदा पावहिं सुखहि नहिं भय सोक न रोग।।20।।
>
> Devoted to duty each according to his own caste and stage of life, the people trod the path of the Vedas and enjoyed happiness. They knew no fear, nor sorrow nor disease.
>
> दैहिक दैविक भौतिक तापा। राम राज नहिं काहुहि ब्यापा।।
>
> सब नर करहिं परस्पर प्रीती। चलहिं स्वधर्म निरत श्रुति नीती।।
>
> चारिउ चरन धर्म जग माहीं। पूरि रहा सपनेहुँ अघ नाहीं।।
>
> राम भगति रत नर अरु नारी। सकल परम गति के अधिकारी।।
>
> अल्पमृत्यु नहिं कवनिउ पीरा। सब सुंदर सब बिरुज सरीरा।।
>
> नहिं दरिद्र कोउ दुखी न दीना। नहिं कोउ अबुध न लच्छन हीना।।
>
> सब निर्दंभ धर्मरत पुनी। नर अरु नारि चतुर सब गुनी।।
>
> सब गुनग्य पंडित सब ग्यानी। सब कृतग्य नहिं कपट सयानी।।
>
> Under the rule of Råma there was none who suffered from affliction of any
>   kind whether of the body, or proceeding from divine or supernatural agencies or that caused by another living being. All men loved one another : each followed one's prescribed duty, conformably to the precepts of the Vedas. Dharma with its four pillars (viz., truth, purity of both external and internal, compassion and charity) reigned everywhere throughout the world; no one even dreamt of sin. Men and women alike were devoted to Sri Råma's worship and all were qualified for final beatitude. There was no
>   premature death nor suffering of any kind; everyone was comely and sound of body. No one was destitute, afflicted or miserable; no one was stupid or devoid of auspicious marks. All were unaffectedly good, pious and virtuous; all were clever and accomplished of both men and women. Everyone recognized the merits of others and was learned and wise nay, everyone acknowledged the services and benefits received from others and there
>   was no guileful prudence.
>
> राम राज नभगेस सुनु सचराचर जग माहिं।। 
>   काल कर्म सुभाव गुन कृत दुख काहुहि नाहिं।।21।।
>
> Listen, O king of the birds, (continues Kåkabhusundi) during Sri Råmaís reign there was not a creature in this world, animate or inanimate, that was liable to any of the sufferings attributable to time, past conduct, personal temperament and character.
>
> दंड जतिन्ह कर भेद जहँ नर्तक नृत्य समाज। 
>   जीतहु मनहि सुनिअ अस रामचंद्र कें राज।।22।।
>
> Danda was never seen save in the hands of the recluse and Bheda too had
>   ceased to exist except among the dancers in a dancing party. Even so the order Conquer was heard only with reference to the mind throughout the realm of Sri Råmacandra.

Answer (score 6):

> न पर्यदेवन्विधवा न च व्यालकृतं भयम् |
>
> न व्याधिजं भयन् वापि रामे राज्यं प्रशासति || ६-१२८-९९
>
> 99. raame = while Rama; prashaasati = was ruling; raajyam = the kingdom; na vidhavaaH paryadevan = there were no widows to lament; na
>       bhayam aasiit = there was no danger; vyaalakR^itam = from wild
>       animals; na bhayam = and no fear; vyaadhijam = born of diseases.
>
> While Rama was ruling the kingdom, there were no widows to lament, nor
>   there was no danger from wild animals, nor any fear born of diseases.
>
> निर्दस्युरभवल्लोको नानर्थः कन् चिदस्पृशत् |
>
> न च स्म वृद्धा बालानां प्रेतकार्याणि कुर्वते || ६-१२८-१००
>
> 100. lokaH = the world; abhavat = became; nirdasyuH = bereft of thieves and robbers; na kashchit = nor anyone; aspR^ishat = felt;
>        anartham = worthless; na vR^iddhaaH cha = nor did old people; kurvate
>        sma = perform; pretakaaryaaNi = obsequies; (concerned); baalaanaam =
>        to youngsters.
>
> The world was bereft of thieves and robberies. No one felt worthless
>   nor did old people perform obsequies concerning youngsters.
>
> सर्वं मुदितमेवासीत्सर्वो धर्मपरोअभवत् |
>
> राममेवानुपश्यन्तो नाभ्यहिन्सन्परस्परम् || ६-१२८-१०१
>
> 101. sarvam = every creature; asiit = felt; muditameva = pleased; sarvaH = everyone; abhavat = became; dharmaparaH = intent on virtue;
>        anupashyantaH = perceiving; raamameva = Rama alone; na abhyahimsan =
>        no one was killing; parasparam = each other.
>
> Every creature felt pleased. Every one was intent on virtue. Turning
>   their eyes towards Rama alone, creatures did not kill one another.
>
> आसन्वर्षसहस्राणि तथा पुत्रसहस्रिणः |
>
> निरामया विशोकाश्च रामे राज्यं प्रशासति || ६-१२८-१०२
>
> 102. raame = (While) Rama; prashaasati = was ruling; raajyam = the kingdom; aasan = (people) lived; varShasahasraaNi = for thousands of
>        years; tathaa = and; putra sahasriNaH = with thousands of progeny;
>        niraamayaaH = free of illness; vishokaashcha = and free of grief.
>
> While Rama was ruling the kingdom, people survived for thousands of
>   years, with thousands of their progeny, all free of illness and grief.
>
> रामो रामो राम इति प्रजानामभवन् कथाः |
>
> रामभूतं जगाभूद्रामे राज्यं प्रशासति || ६-१२८-१०३
>
> 103. raame prashaasati = while Rama ruled; raajyam = the kingdom; kathaaH = the talks; prajaanaam = of the people; abhavan = centred
>        round; raamaH raamaH raamaH iti = Rama; Rama and Rama; jagat = the
>        world; abhuut = became; raama bhuutam = Rama's world.
>
> While Rama ruled the kingdom, the talks of the people centered round
>   Rama, Rama and Rama. The world became Rama's world.
>
> नित्यपुष्पा नित्यफलास्तरवः स्कन्धविस्तृताः |
>
> कालवर्षी च पर्जन्यः सुखस्पर्शश्च मारुतः || ६-१२८-१०४
>
> 104. taravaH = the trees; tatra = there; nitya puShpaaH = were having regular flowers; nitya phalaaH = and regular fruits; nirvraNaaH =
>        without injuries (by pests and insects); parjanyaH = the cloud;
>        kaalavarShii = was raining in time; maarutaH = and wind; sukha
>        sparshaH = was delightful to the touch.
>
> The trees there were bearing flowers and fruits regularly, without any
>   injury by pests and insects. The clouds were raining in time and the
>   wind was delightful to the touch.
>
> ब्राह्मणाः क्षत्रिया वैश्याः शूद्रा लोभविवर्जिताः |
>
> स्वकर्मसु प्रवर्तन्ते तुष्ठाः स्वैरेव कर्मभिः || ६-१२८-१०५
>
> आसन् प्रजा धर्मपरा रामे शासति नानृताः |
>
> 105. braahmaNaaH = Brahmins (the priest-class); kShatriyaaH = Kshatriyas (the warrior-class); vaishyaaH = Vaishyas (the merchants
>        and agriculturists); shuudraaH = Shudras (the servent-class)
>        pravartante = were performing; svakarmasu = their own duties; tuShTaaH
>        = satisfied; svaiH karmabhireva = with their own works; lobhavivarjitaah = bereft of greed; raame = (while) Rama; shaasati =
>        was ruling; prajaaH = the people; aasan = were; dharmaparaaH = intent
>        on virtue; na anR^itaaH = (and lived) without untruth.
>
> Brahmins (the priest-class), Kshatriyas (the warrior-class), Vaishyas
>   (the class of merchants and agriculturists), Shudras (the
>   servant-class) were performing their own duties, satisfied with their
>   own work and bereft of any greed. While Rama was ruling, the people
>   were intent on virtue and lived without telling lies.
>
> सर्वे लक्षणसम्पन्नाः सर्वे धर्मपरायणाः || ६-१२८-१०६
>
> दशवर्षसहस्राणि रामो राज्यमकारयत् |
>
> 106. sarve = all; lakShaNa sampannaaH = were endowed with good characteristics; sarve = all; dharmaparaayaNaaH = were engaged in
>        virtue; raamaH = Rama; akaarayat = was engaged; raajyam = in kingship;
>        varShasahasraaNi = for one thousand years.
>
> All the people were endowed with excellent characteristics. All were
>   engaged in virtue. Rama was engaged in the kingship thus for one
>   thousand years.

[Source](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga128/yuddha_128_frame.htm)

Answer (score 4):

> As supreme personality of godhead and the supreme controller of all
>   the worlds, Shri Rama stills rules the earth indirectly, but it was
>   the  auspicious effect of Rama's rule in personal that all the people
>   became intent on virtue and completely satisfied. So only those people
>   can get ultimate peace, pleasure, prosperity and bliss of Rama-RAjya
>   who feel and see that Rama is the king of all the worlds and take
>   refuge  in his lotus feet with all love and devotion.
>
> While in direct rule of Shri RAma as king of Ayodhya, everyone was
>   blessed with all auspicious qualities, Dharma (righteousness), peace, 
>   prosperity, complete satisfaction, and bliss.
>
> Here Maharshi Valmiki describes the beauty of Rama-Rajya:
>
> न पर्यदेवन्विधवा न च व्यालकृतं भयम् |
>
> न व्याधिजं भयन् वापि रामे राज्यं प्रशासति ||
>
> [श्रीमद् वाल्मीकि रामायण 6, 128|99]
>
> While Shri Rama was ruling the kingdom, there were no widows to
>   lament, nor there was no danger from wild animals, nor any fear born
>   of diseases!  [Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmāyaṇam 6-128-99]
>
> निर्दस्युरभवल्लोको नानर्थः कन् चिदस्पृशत् |
>
> न च स्म वृद्धा बालानां प्रेतकार्याणि कुर्वते ||    [श्रीमद् वाल्मीकि
>   रामायण 6, 128|100]
>
> The world was bereft of thieves and robberies. No one felt worthless
>   nor did old people perform obsequies concerning youngsters.
>   
> [Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmāyaṇam 6-128-100]
>
> सर्वं मुदितमेवासीत्सर्वो धर्मपरोअभवत् |
>
> राममेवानुपश्यन्तो नाभ्यहिन्सन्परस्परम् ||
>
> [श्रीमद् वाल्मीकि रामायण 6, 128|101]
>
> Every creature felt pleased! Every one was intent on virtue! Turning
>   their eyes towards Shri Rama alone, creatures did not kill one
>   another.
>
> [Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmāyaṇam 6-128-101]
>
> Not just only Human being but every creature felt pleased in Shri
>   RAma-RAjya. All were intent on virtue. Not just Human-Beings or
>   deities or  demons, but even trees, beasts, birds, etc, all were
>   engrossed in looking at Shri Rama alone!
>
> आसन्वर्षसहस्राणि तथा पुत्रसहस्रिणः |
>
> निरामया विशोकाश्च रामे राज्यं प्रशासति ||
>
> [श्रीमद् वाल्मीकि रामायण 6, 128|102]
>
> While Shri Rama was ruling the kingdom, people survived for thousands
>   of years, with thousands of their progeny, all free of illness and
>   grief.
>
> [Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmāyaṇam 6-128-102]
>
> See the greatness of Rama's kingship that everyone survived for
>   thousand (1000) Years without any illness and grief. None of the three
>   fold agony  of this material would could touch anyone while Shri Rama
>   was ruling this earth.
>
> रामो रामो राम इति प्रजानामभवन् कथाः |
>
> रामभूतं जगाभूद्रामे राज्यं प्रशासति ||
>
> [श्रीमद् वाल्मीकि रामायण 6, 128|103]
>
> While Shri Rama ruled the kingdom, the talks of the people centered
>   round Rama, Rama and Rama alone. The world became Rama's world.
>
> [Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmāyaṇam 6-128-103]
>
> The world was transformed into Shri Rama's world. No one was
>   interested in any other thing apart from their King Rama who was very
>   embodiment of  righteousness (Dharma).
>
> नित्यपुष्पा नित्यफलास्तरवः स्कन्धविस्तृताः |
>
> कालवर्षी च पर्जन्यः सुखस्पर्शश्च मारुतः ||
>
> ब्राह्मणाः क्षत्रिया वैश्याः शूद्रा लोभविवर्जिताः |
>
> स्वकर्मसु प्रवर्तन्ते तुष्ठाः स्वैरेव कर्मभिः ||
>
> आसन् प्रजा धर्मपरा रामे शासति नानृताः |
>
> सर्वे लक्षणसम्पन्नाः सर्वे धर्मपरायणाः ||
>
> [श्रीमद् वाल्मीकि रामायण 6, 128|104-106]
>
> The trees there were bearing flowers and fruits regularly, without any
>   injury by pests and insects. The clouds were raining in time and the 
>   wind was delightful to the touch.
>
> [Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmāyaṇam 6-128-104]
>
> Brahmins (the priest-class), Kshatriyas (the warrior-class), Vaishyas
>   (the class of merchants and agriculturists), Shudras (the
>   servant-class) were  performing their own duties, satisfied with their
>   own work and bereft of any greed.
>
> [Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmāyaṇam 6-128-105]
>
> While Rama was ruling, the people were intent on virtue and lived
>   without telling lies. All the people were endowed with excellent
>   characteristics.  All were engaged in virtue.
>
> [Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmāyaṇam 6-128-106]

[Source](http://lordrama.co.in/rama-rajya.html)