# What is the specialty of Rama Rajya?

Tags: ramayana, rama

There is already [a question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15047/3869) on this topic Rama Rajya, but the content of this question is different.  ***And, hence, it is not a duplicate.***

---

[Sri Mahatma Gandhi](https://www.mkgandhi.org/momgandhi/chap67.htm) said about Rama Rajya (Rule of Sri Rama) as follows:

> Whether Rama of my imagination ever lived or not on this earth, the
>   **ancient ideal of Ramarajya** is undoubtedly one of true democracy in
>   which the **meanest citizen could be sure of swift justice** without an
>   elaborate and costly procedure. Even the dog is described by the poet
>   to have received justice under Ramarajya.

---

Now, the following is the description, from [Bala Kanda](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga6/bala_6_frame.htm), about status of people in the rule of King Dasaratha.

I am providing only 4 slokas for understanding of the reader as to how the rule of King Dasaratha was like.  Remaining slokas can be read at the link provided above.

> तस्मिन्पुरवरे हृष्टा धर्मात्मानो बहुश्रुताः | नरास्तुष्टा धनैः स्वैः
>   स्वैरलुब्धाः सत्यवादिनः ||१-६-६
>
> In that best city Ayodhya all are exuberant yet virtuous ones, and
>   scholars are variously learned ones, people are satisfied with their
>   own riches, they have no greed, and they advocate truthfulness alone.
>
> नाल्पसंनिचयः कश्चिदासीत्तस्मिन्पुरोत्तमे | कुटुंबी यो
>   ह्यसिद्धार्थोऽगवाश्वधनधान्यवान् || १-६-७
>
> None with meagre accumulations is there in that great city and no
>   householder is there without unearned means, and without cows, horses,
>   monies or cereals and who could not sustain his family.
>
> कामी वा न कदर्यो वा नृशंसः पुरुषः क्वचित् | द्रष्टुं शक्यमयोध्यायां
>   नाविद्वान्न च नास्तिकः || १-६-८
>
> None can see a lustful person, or a miser or a cruel one anywhere in
>   that Ayodhya, along with nondescripts or non-believers, for there are
>   no such persons.
>
> सर्वे नराश्च नार्यश्च धर्मशीलाः सुसंयताः | उदिताः शीलवृत्ताभ्यां
>   महर्षय इवामलाः || १-६-९
>
> All the ladies and gentlemen in that city are virtuous in mind,
>   self-controlled ones, they are all self-satisfied like great saints,
>   and both in their conduct and character they are blameless.

---

My question is when the rule of King Dasaratha is like an idealistic society, what is the speciality of Rama Rajya?

Answer (score 2):

Rama Rajya speciality is described at the end of yuddha kanda.

http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga128/yuddha_128_frame.htm

> न पर्यदेवन्विधवा न च व्यालकृतं भयम् |
>   न व्याधिजं भयन् वापि रामे राज्यं प्रशासति || ६-१२८-९९
>
> 99. raame = while Rama; prashaasati = was ruling; raajyam = the kingdom; na vidhavaaH paryadevan = there were no widows to lament; na bhayam aasiit = there was no danger; vyaalakR^itam = from wild animals; na bhayam = and no fear; vyaadhijam = born of diseases.
>
> **While Rama was ruling the kingdom, there were no widows to lament, nor there was no danger from wild animals, nor any fear born of diseases.**
>
> निर्दस्युरभवल्लोको नानर्थः कन् चिदस्पृशत् |
>   न च स्म वृद्धा बालानां प्रेतकार्याणि कुर्वते || ६-१२८-१००
>
> 100. lokaH = the world; abhavat = became; nirdasyuH = bereft of thieves and robbers; na kashchit = nor anyone; aspR^ishat = felt; anartham = worthless; na vR^iddhaaH cha = nor did old people; kurvate sma = perform; pretakaaryaaNi = obsequies; (concerned); baalaanaam = to youngsters.
>
> **The world was bereft of thieves and robberies. No one felt worthless nor did old people perform obsequies concerning youngsters.**
>
> सर्वं मुदितमेवासीत्सर्वो धर्मपरोअभवत् |
>   राममेवानुपश्यन्तो नाभ्यहिन्सन्परस्परम् || ६-१२८-१०१
>
> 101. sarvam = every creature; asiit = felt; muditameva = pleased; sarvaH = everyone; abhavat = became; dharmaparaH = intent on virtue; anupashyantaH = perceiving; raamameva = Rama alone; na abhyahimsan = no one was killing; parasparam = each other.
>
> **Every creature felt pleased. Every one was intent on virtue. Turning their eyes towards Rama alone, creatures did not kill one another.**
>
> आसन्वर्षसहस्राणि तथा पुत्रसहस्रिणः |
>   निरामया विशोकाश्च रामे राज्यं प्रशासति || ६-१२८-१०२
>
> 102. raame = (While) Rama; prashaasati = was ruling; raajyam = the kingdom; aasan = (people) lived; varShasahasraaNi = for thousands of years; tathaa = and; putra sahasriNaH = with thousands of progeny; niraamayaaH = free of illness; vishokaashcha = and free of grief.
>
> **While Rama was ruling the kingdom, people survived for thousands of years, with thousands of their progeny, all free of illness and grief.**
>
> रामो रामो राम इति प्रजानामभवन् कथाः |
>   रामभूतं जगाभूद्रामे राज्यं प्रशासति || ६-१२८-१०३
>
> 103. raame prashaasati = while Rama ruled; raajyam = the kingdom; kathaaH = the talks; prajaanaam = of the people; abhavan = centred round; raamaH raamaH raamaH iti = Rama; Rama and Rama; jagat = the world; abhuut = became; raama bhuutam = Rama's world.
>
> **While Rama ruled the kingdom, the talks of the people centered round Rama, Rama and Rama. The world became Rama's world.**
>
> नित्यपुष्पा नित्यफलास्तरवः स्कन्धविस्तृताः |
>   कालवर्षी च पर्जन्यः सुखस्पर्शश्च मारुतः || ६-१२८-१०४
>
> 104. taravaH = the trees; tatra = there; nitya puShpaaH = were having regular flowers; nitya phalaaH = and regular fruits; nirvraNaaH = without injuries (by pests and insects); parjanyaH = the cloud; kaalavarShii = was raining in time; maarutaH = and wind; sukha sparshaH = was delightful to the touch.
>
> **The trees there were bearing flowers and fruits regularly, without any injury by pests and insects. The clouds were raining in time and the wind was delightful to the touch.**
>
> ब्राह्मणाः क्षत्रिया वैश्याः शूद्रा लोभविवर्जिताः |
>   स्वकर्मसु प्रवर्तन्ते तुष्ठाः स्वैरेव कर्मभिः || ६-१२८-१०५
>   आसन् प्रजा धर्मपरा रामे शासति नानृताः |
>
> 105. braahmaNaaH = Brahmins (the priest-class); kShatriyaaH = Kshatriyas (the warrior-class); vaishyaaH = Vaishyas (the merchants and agriculturists); shuudraaH = Shudras (the servent-class) pravartante = were performing; svakarmasu = their own duties; tuShTaaH = satisfied; svaiH karmabhireva = with their own works; lobhavivarjitaah = bereft of greed; raame = (while) Rama; shaasati = was ruling; prajaaH = the people; aasan = were; dharmaparaaH = intent on virtue; na anR^itaaH = (and lived) without untruth.
>
> **Brahmins (the priest-class), Kshatriyas (the warrior-class), Vaishyas (the class of merchants and agriculturists), Shudras (the servant-class) were performing their own duties, satisfied with their own work and bereft of any greed. While Rama was ruling, the people were intent on virtue and lived without telling lies.**
>
> सर्वे लक्षणसम्पन्नाः सर्वे धर्मपरायणाः || ६-१२८-१०६
>   दशवर्षसहस्राणि रामो राज्यमकारयत् |
>
> 106. sarve = all; lakShaNa sampannaaH = were endowed with good characteristics; sarve = all; dharmaparaayaNaaH = were engaged in virtue; raamaH = Rama; akaarayat = was engaged; raajyam = in kingship; varShasahasraaNi = for one thousand years.
>
> **All the people were endowed with excellent characteristics. All were engaged in virtue. Rama was engaged in the kingship thus for one thousand years.**

**Addendum**

The verses in the Bala kanda describe only the city of Ayodhya. They describe the characteristics of Ayodhya city and not that of Dasaratha's rule.

Comment: Please read my question again.  Similar situation was prevailing even in the rule of King Dasaratha also.  What is the speciality of Rama rAjya?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv The situation described in bala kanda, applies to Ayodhya only. It looks more like a characteristic of the city than due to Dasaratha's rule.

Comment: Sorry.  That applies to entire Kosala Kingdom.  Start from 5th Sarga

Comment: @srimannayanakv Even though 1.5.5 talks about Kosala, from 1.5.6, the description is about the city of Ayodhya. There is also no mention that any of the city's characteristics are due to Dasaratha's rule. This is my understanding. If your understanding differs, it is fine.